# Directly set renderbuffer contents in iOS OpenGL ES?

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, texture-mapping, metal

I'm trying to get my Metal iOS app to work with Google's Cardboard VR SDK, which unfortunately only works with OpenGL ES.  I'm able to get the correct head transforms from the SDK and render the images in Metal to a texture.  Now what I need to do is take that texture and stick it in the OpenGL ES render buffer, so that the VR SDK can apply lens distortion and display it.

I figure I can display it by rendering a texture-mapped quad in OpenGL, but is there a simpler way where I can just transfer the contents of the texture map image to the OpenGL render buffer directly?  It seems a waste to have to go through the rendering step when I just need to get the contents of one image to another...

Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to avoid the fullscreen quad pass if you have control over the configuration of the framebuffer used by the SDK. Specifically, you could use the IOSurface API to create an IOSurface-backed MTLTexture into which you render your scene, then wrap the IOSurface in an OpenGL ES texture via the CVOpenGLESTextureCache API. If you can provide a texture created in this way as the renderbuffer, you won't have to run the extra pass to interoperate between these API. I've never done any of this myself.

Comment: Well, yes I was planning on doing something like that - but that would still require drawing a texture mapped quad in OpenGL, wouldn’t it?  I was hoping to just copy my Metal-rendered image data directly into the OpenGL framebuffer - thereby avoiding any rendering in OpenGL.